# How to transform a Syncfusion Sidebars <span> class to my custom design?

Tags: html, css, blazor, sidebar, syncfusion

Currently I've added a sidebar into my Syncfusion Blazor project and this sidebar has a sidebar item that expands the menu to more width or resize it to smaller, however this design is not something what I want. What I got is this:

Sidebar opened:

[image]

Sidebar Closed:

[image]

Now the issue is the sidebar item "< Menu", clicking on this item will open the full width or sidebar or close it(if was opened). What I'm trying to reach is something like this:

[image]

The image above represents one sidebar item, same as "< Menu>. I'm trying to transform the "< Menu" sidebar item to something like this, does anyone know how to achieve this?

Sidebar code:

```
   <SfSidebar Width="220px" DockSize="72px" EnableDock="true" Position="SidebarPosition.Left" @ref="Sidebar" HtmlAttributes="@HtmlAttribute">
        <ChildContent>
            <div class="dock">
                <ul>
                    <li class="sidebar-item" id="toggle" @onclick="@Toggle">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="">
                            <span class="e-icons expand"></span>
                            <span class="e-text" title="home">Menu</span>
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="page1" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                            <span class="oi oi-dashboard" style="font-size: 30px; margin-right: 15px;"></span>
                            <span class="e-text" title="home">Page 1</span>
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="page2" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                            <span class="oi oi-graph" style="font-size: 30px; margin-right: 15px;"></span>
                            <span class="e-text" title="profile">Page 2</span>
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="()=>expandShipDetailsSubNav = !expandShipDetailsSubNav">
                            <span class="oi oi-eye" style="font-size: 30px; margin-right: 15px;"></span>
                            <span class="e-text" title="info">Page 3</span>
                        </NavLink>
                        @if (expandShipDetailsSubNav)
                        {
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/page3/1" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                                Vessel 1
                            </NavLink>
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/page3/2" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">
                                Vessel 2
                            </NavLink>
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/page3/3" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">
                                Vessel 3
                            </NavLink>
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/page3/4" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">
                                Vessel 4
                            </NavLink>
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/page3/5" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">
                                Vessel 5
                            </NavLink>

                        }
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="()=>expandReportingSubNav = !expandReportingSubNav">
                            <span class="oi oi-file" style="font-size: 30px; margin-right: 15px;"></span>
                            <span class="e-text" title="info">Page 4</span>
                        </NavLink>
                        @if (expandReportingSubNav)
                        {
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/page4/1" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                                EU MRV
                            </NavLink>
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/page4/2" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">
                                IMO DCS
                            </NavLink>
                        }
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="page 5" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                            <span class="oi oi-cog" style="font-size: 30px; margin-right: 15px;"></span>
                            <span class="e-text" title="home">Page 5</span>
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-item" id="li6">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" @onclick="@OnBtnClick">
                            <span class="oi oi-power-standby" style="font-size: 30px; margin-right: 15px;"></span>
                            <span class="e-text" title="home">Sign Out</span>
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </ChildContent>
    </SfSidebar>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
}

.sub-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#wrapper .sub-title .column {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
/* custom code start */
.center {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.sb-content-tab .center {
    display: block;
}
/* custom code end */
/* end of content area styles */
/* Sidebar styles */
.dockSidebar.e-sidebar.e-right.e-close {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.dockSidebar .e-icons::before {
    font-size: 25px;
}
/* dockbar icon Style */
.dockSidebar .home::before {
    content: '\e102';
}

.dockSidebar .profile::before {
    content: '\e10c';
}

.dockSidebar .info::before {
    content: '\e11b';
}

.dockSidebar .settings::before {
    content: '\e10b';
}

.e-sidebar .expand::before,
.e-sidebar.e-right.e-open .expand::before {
    content: '\e10f';
}

.e-sidebar.e-open .expand::before,
.e-sidebar.e-right .expand::before {
    content: '\e10e';
}
/* end of dockbar icon Style */
.dockSidebar.e-close .sidebar-item {
    /*padding: 5px 20px;*/
}

.dockSidebar.e-dock.e-close span.e-text {
    display: none;
}

.dockSidebar.e-dock.e-open span.e-text {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dockSidebar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dockSidebar ul {
    padding: 0px;
}

.dockSidebar.e-sidebar ul li:hover span {
    /*color: white;*/
}

.dockSidebar span.e-icons {
    color: #c0c2c5;
    line-height: 2
}

.e-open .e-icons {
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.e-open .e-text {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.sidebar-item {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px #e5e5e58a solid;
}

.e-sidebar.e-open .sidebar-item {
    text-align: left;
    /*padding-left: 15px;*/
    color: #c0c2c5;
}

.dockSidebar.e-sidebar {
    background: #2d323e;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* custom generated icons styles */
@@font-face {
    font-family: 'e-icons';
    src: url(data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
/* end of custom generated icons styles */
/* custom code start */
.sf-new .sb-header,
.sf-new .sb-bread-crumb,
.sf-new #action-description,
.sf-new .sb-action-description,
.sf-new .e-tab-header,
.sf-new .description-section,
.sf-new #description-section,
.sf-new #description,
.sf-new #navigation-btn,
.sf-new .sb-toolbar-splitter,
.sf-new .sb-footer, .sf-new #left-sidebar, .sb-component-name {
    display: none
}

.sf-new .sb-right-pane.e-view {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}

.sb-action-description.sb-rightpane-padding {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.description-section {
    padding-top: 0;
}

#sb-content-header {
    display: none
}

#content-tab.sb-content-tab {
    height: 100% !important;
}

.sf-new .container-fluid,
.sf-new .container-fluid .control-section,
#sidebar-section, description-section sb-rightpane-padding {
    padding: 0;
}

.sb-component-name.sb-rightpane-padding {
    margin-top: -56px;
}

.sb-right-pane.e-view {
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.sb-desktop-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}

.sb-component-name h1 {
    padding-top: 0;
}

.sf-new .sb-content.e-view {
    top: 0;
}
/* end of newTab support */
/* custom code end */
/* end of sidebar styles */

/* Custom css*/

.sidebar-item {
    color: #BBBBBB !important;
}

a {
    color: #BBBBBB !important;
}


.sidebar-item:hover {
    color: white !important;
}

a:hover {
    color: white !important;
}

/* Custom button */
.e-custom {
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
}

    .e-custom, .e-custom:hover, .e-custom:focus, .e-custom:active {
        background-color: #ff6e40;
        color: #fff;
    }

#button-control {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8% 0;
    text-align: center;
}

@@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #button-control {
        margin-left: -3%;
    }
}

.button-section {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

#button-control .col-xs-12 {
    margin: 15px 0;
}

@@font-face {
    font-family: 'button-icons';
    src: url(data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.e-btn-sb-icons {
    font-family: 'button-icons';
    line-height: 1;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.e-play-icon::before {
    content: '\e701';
}

.e-pause-icon::before {
    content: '\e705';
}

.e-open-icon::before {
    content: '\e70d';
}

.e-add-icon::before {
    content: '\e70a';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have checked your requirement with Sidebar component. When disabling the EnableDock property of sidebar, it expand/collapse the sidebar based on full width of Sidebar component. Refer the below link to know more about the EnableDock property.

https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/sidebar/docking-sidebar/

Based on your shared image, you are expecting to open the sidebar when clicking the sticky button. To achieve this requirement, you need to add the sticky button in the SF Sidebar element then you can expand or collapse the sidebar component when clicking the sticky button click.

We have prepared a simple sample in which have positioned Sidebar in to appear left end of the screen and added sticky button to it, as like you expected to have with Sidebar.

```
/* sample-level sticky button styles */  
  .e-sidebar #e-leftSticky { 
        position: relative; 
        cursor: pointer; 
        top: 50%; 
        height: 30px; 
        left: -57px; 
        border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px; 
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000428, #004e92); 
        text-align: left; 
        font-size: 18px; 
        text-align: center; 
        text-indent: 10px; 
        -ms-transform: rotate(270deg); 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); 
        transform: rotate(270deg); 
    } 
 
    .e-sidebar.e-close, .e-sidebar.e-open { 
        overflow: initial; 
        visibility: visible !important; 
    }
```

Refer the sample link below.
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Responsive_Sidebar37687257.zip

To know more about the Sidebar component, refer the below links.

UG Documentation-https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/sidebar/getting-started/

Demo link-https://blazor.syncfusion.com/demos/sidebar/default-functionalities/

API reference-https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/blazor/Syncfusion.Blazor~Syncfusion.Blazor.Navigations.ISidebar_members.html

Please let us know, if you need any further assistance.

Regards,

Sowmiya.P